# Python - Read files from folder and Write files to different folder

Tags: python, file

Read list of files in Folder, check if 7th column in every line of each file not equal to '*', then have to write those lines to each file in output folder

```
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import glob
import os

input_dir = Path('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\Cobol/')

inpfiles = input_dir.glob('*.CBL')

#Process files for writing uncommented lines
def process_files_uncomment(inpfiles):
    global writereccount
    for inpfile in inpfiles:
        writereccount = 0
        try:
            inpfile_handle = open(inpfile, 'r')
            line = inpfile_handle.readlines()
            for i in line:
                if i[0] == '\t':       #Condition to check if line starts with tab
                    pass
                elif i[6] != '*':      #Condition to check 6th column of line
                    writereccount += 1
                    f=open(os.path.join('C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\TempCOBOL\\Updated',
                    os.path.basename(inpfile)) , 'w')
                    f.write(i)
                    #
                else:
                    pass
            
            print('Total number of UN-COMMENTED LINES           :', writereccount)                
        except:
            print('Exception while Reading File')

process_files_uncomment(inpfiles)
```

---

Output in Terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\Python-1> & C:/Users/user1/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/user1/Python-1/process_files_writeuncomment.py
Total number of UN-COMMENTED LINES           : 187
Total number of UN-COMMENTED LINES           : 182
```

---

Actual output of files in Folder:

This PC > Desktop > TempCOBOL > Updated

```
    Name                   Date Modified              Type                 Size
    ABCDEFGH.CBL           9/8/2022 time              CBL file             1KB
    IJKLMNOP.CBL           9/8/2022 time              CBL file             1KB
```

---

Problem:
Script executed and Read 2 CBL files in the Folder, and created 2 CBL files in output folder. The output CBL files to have 1) ABCDEFGH.CBL - 187 lines and 2) IJKLMNOP.CBL - 182 lines

However, the actual output lines in

```
1) ABCDEFGH.CBL - 1 line

               030100           MASTER-CAT.                                            04050000

2) IJKLMNOP.CBL - 1 line

               030100           MASTER-CAT.                                            04050000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing :

```
os.path.basename(inpfile)) , 'w')
```

by

```
os.path.basename(inpfile)) , 'a')
```

because w erase the existing file with last line, every new line